# example of an one form from a $C^{\infty}$ function

Tags: differential-geometry

For any $C^{\infty}$ function $U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ we  can construct a $1$ form $df$ called a differential of $f$ as follows $p\in U$ and $X_p\in T_p(U)$ we define $$(df)_p(X_p)=X_p f$$

I want an easy example to remember the above definition with above notation for the rest of my life! please help.I always forget this.

Comment: Are you familiar with vector calculus?  Gradients?

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ be the 2-sphere. Let $X_p$ be the 0-vector along the equator and poles, and the unit vector in the direction of the nearest pole otherwise. Then $X_pf$ is the scalar projection of $f$ onto the oriented meridian line whenever $X_p$ is nonzero.

EDIT: The $df$ notation is by comparison with the derivative. In the notation $df/dx$, the ratio is between infinitesimal numbers - hence the limit definition of the derivative. The key is to think of the two numbers as points on a line, and taking the tangent line as zooming in on the curve $f$ until you can't tell it's not a straight line.

When you embed the tangent line to $f$ at $p$ in the tangent space to $\Bbb{R}^{2}$ at $p$, which is $\Bbb{R}^{2}$ with the $dx$ and $dy$ similarly given by embeddings of tangent lines, you can calculate slope in that vector space with respect to $dx$ like it's any coordinate system for $R^2$.

Comment: This is almost an answer. Do you have a reason that this should correspond to $df$? Otherwise you've given an interpretation of $X_p(f)$ in a specific example, but not a way to remember $df_p(X)=X(f)$.

Comment: That should work.